# How to subtract values from two different sqlite3 tables in python

Tags: python, database, python-3.x, sqlite

Assuming i have a main table containing a list of items and quantities. And a second table having also a list of items and quantities.
Eg.

Main Table(Stock)(Table1)

```
----------
Items  | QTY
----------
sugar  | 14
mango  | 10
apple  | 50
berry  | 1
```

Second Table(populated by user input)(Table 2)

```
----------
Items  |QTY
----------
sugar  |1
mango  |5
apple  |8
berry  |1
```

How do i get the item and quantity from the table 2, compare the item name with that of Table 1,such that if same it moves on to subtract Table 2's value from that of Table 1
In summary, how do i subtract values from two different tables in sqlite3 python
Any ideas would help so much.
A simple code example would also help much.Thank you

Comment: please show us what you've already tried

Comment: Do you want to update the first table?

Comment: Yes,that is what i want to do

Comment: Is there away I could get the two  quantity values from the table with corresponding item name  and subtract it without also storing it in an sqlite3 database...Forgive me asking such noob questions, that is because I am new to databases

Comment: Please decide whether you want to update the table or not. If you have two different questions, [ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) two questions.

Comment: Okay.I will ask that through another question.Thanks for the help guys,really appreciated it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `replace into` with `join`:

```
replace into Stock(Items, qty)    
select s.Items,
    s.qty - t.qty
from Stock s
join Second_table t on s.Items = t.Items;
```

The above works if there is a unique key defined on the Items column.

You can try using correlated subquery:

```
update stock
set qty = qty - (
        select sum(qty)
        from second_table t
        where stock.items = t.items
        )
```